# How can you avoid a world dictatorship, with machines as enforcers (police, military)?

Tags: robots, dictatorship

I'm writing a story and I got a bit stuck. The world where the story takes place is at a point in its development where they no longer use humans as military personnel nor as police. When military or police contact with humans is necessary it is done by robots. And the input for them is given by DOJ's or manufacturers.

The issue I'm having is that, how do you avoid countries being taken over by a few humans who are at the controls?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please provide additional details to answer your question, according to what is explained in our [help]

Comment: The other countries have robots also.

Comment: The conventional method with very powerful government services is to set them against each other. Trying to take over the country with police robots? The military robots might have something to say about that. Fancy a coup with your military robots? Well, we'll see how long they last without constant maintenance from the logistics corps robots. Etc.

Comment: @Cadence The Emperor's approach, I see.

Comment: You can't. Obey.

Answer (score 1):

Partly you can resolve the issue by dividing control between a large number of AI systems so that no one AI has overarching control over all the others. Division of responsibility can be geographical or functional or a mixture of both based on population density and need.

Most stores about this kind of thing assume 'Skynet' or its analogue control everything. Why? Intelligence on day to day operations can be exchanged and shared via routine email packets or 'viewed/listened to' as video feeds or radio broadcasts or otherwise physically extracted from a communication network before being 'read' by the AI concerned. In addition the AI's themselves can be built so program changes/updates are not possible without *direct physical access* to specific secure locations occupied by the AI in question.

As a simple example you computer is connected to the internet. But there's nothing stooping you from having a second computer with no direct physical connection to the net in your house. It can be connected to cameras and other remote **sensors** (such as a drone flying overhead). Someone can jam input to its sensors, even trick/spoof it by transmitting false readings if they can break the encryption etc but unless they break in and physically access the computer they can't change its basic programming. Any info from the net you want to migrate across to the other computer would have to be processed separately by you.

The result would be 'clunky', The AIs would have delays in receiving certain types of info that wouldn't be an issue with direct integration to the net. But they wouldn't be as easily hacked either.

The other issue is vetting support staff. They would have to be loyal to the region or function concerned, well paid, screened  integrity and face severe penalties for attempting to corrupt a particular AI's integrity. End of the day no system human or artificial is 100% tamper proof. Just look at your Government.

Answer (score 0):

**World dictatorship can be avoided** by giving full oversight and overriding mandate of all actions of the police and military organizations to an objective all-encompassing artificial intelligence entity… *(Just wish the AI have no flaws or internal conflicts  )*

Answer (score 0):

More or less the same idea as already mentioned in one of comments. All these machine-enforcers need extensive maintenance and a logistic infrastructure, mostly performed and planned by humans. Without these things in place, the machines stop working in hours/days/weeks.